# Custom SQL Query in Tableau produces incorrect output when same query in SSMS runs as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, rowcount, tableau-desktop

I built SQL query that works as expected when I execute it in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, however when I use same query in Tableau (Custom SQL query), some columns (where aggregation was performed) are showing incorrect output (always **0**).

Issue is in the lines of code shown here. I guess `@@ROWCOUNT` could be an issue.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN a.LocationName = 'Home' THEN @@ROWCOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS CountHomeServices,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.LocationName = 'Office' THEN @@ROWCOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS CountOfficeServices
```

Is there a way to make it work in Tableau?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what you expect @@rowcount to return in the middle of your query?  It represents the rowcount from the prior statement (in that session), so describing it in isolation is confusing/odd.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're just counting the rows with each LocationName, replace `@@ROWCOUNT` with `1`.

Comment: OMG, that actually worked. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

A more intuitive approach would be

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.LocationName = 'Home' THEN a.LocationName END) AS CountHomeServices,
COUNT(CASE WHEN a.LocationName = 'Office' THEN a.LocationName END) AS CountOfficeServices
```

Comment: This is the best answer! Using @@ROWCOUNT in the middle of two queries is a bad idea!